# Using Boost.asio with cmake?

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, boost-asio

I want to static link boost.asio to my small project without external libs (having only single exe/bin file in result to distribute it). Boost.asio requires Boost.system and i start to drown trying to figure out how to compile this all.
How to use Boost.asio with cmake?

Comment: All boost components can be linked statically. What is your problem again?

Comment: i have googled it lots of times, every time i find some issue why i can't compile it. So i made Question how to exactly do it. I can't compile any part of boost with cmake, neither know how to use it on my project with cmake statically.

Comment: Take a look at contents of `FindBoost.cmake`. You can find it in `Modules/` dir of CMake installation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I understand the actual question, it is fundamentally asking how to statically link against 3rd party libraries in CMake.

In my environment, I have installed Boost to `/opt/boost`.

The easiest way is to use `FindBoost.cmake` provided in a CMake installation:

```
set(BOOST_ROOT /opt/boost)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS system)

include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
add_executable(example example.cpp)
target_link_libraries(example ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

A variant that finds all Boost libraries and explicitly links against the system library:

```
set(BOOST_ROOT /opt/boost)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED)

include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
add_executable(example example.cpp)
target_link_libraries(example ${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY})
```

If you do not have a proper Boost installation, then there are two approaches to statically link against the libraries.  The first approach creates an imported CMake target:

```
add_library(boost_system STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET boost_system PROPERTY
  IMPORTED_LOCATION /opt/boost/lib/libboost_system.a 
)

include_directories(/opt/boost/include)
add_executable(example example.cpp)
target_link_libraries(example boost_system)
```

And the alternative is to explicitly list the library in `target_link_libraries` rather than the target:

```
include_directories(/opt/boost/include)
add_executable(example example.cpp)
target_link_libraries(example /opt/boost/lib/libboost_system.a)
```